# How to setup FFMPEGInterop to Use DRM playready

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, uwp, drm, playready

I am using FFMPEGInterop class to play UWP video. I need to play it with playready setup but am running into issues.

I can play playready with just mediaplayerelement and creating the protection manager, but when I create a FFMPEGMSS to stream it, than it fails. Says value is out of range when adding the protection manager to the MediaStreamSource.

```
var StreamSource = FFmpegMSS.GetMediaStreamSource();
var protectionManager = new Windows.Media.Protection.MediaProtectionManager();
Windows.Foundation.Collections.PropertySet cpSystems = new Windows.Foundation.Collections.PropertySet();
cpSystems.Add("{F4637010-03C3-42CD-B932-B48ADF3A6A54}", "Microsoft.Media.PlayReadyClient.PlayReadyWinRTTrustedInput"); //Playready
protectionManager.Properties.Add("Windows.Media.Protection.MediaProtectionSystemIdMapping", cpSystems);
protectionManager.Properties.Add("Windows.Media.Protection.MediaProtectionSystemId", "{F4637010-03C3-42CD-B932-B48ADF3A6A54}");
protectionManager.ServiceRequested += ProtectionManager_ServiceRequested;
protectionManager.ComponentLoadFailed += ProtectionManager_ComponentLoadFailed;

protectionManager.Properties.Add("Windows.Media.Protection.MediaProtectionContainerGuid", "{9A04F079-9840-4286-AB92-E65BE0885F95}");

var supportsHardwareDrm = PlayReadyStatics.CheckSupportedHardware(PlayReadyHardwareDRMFeatures.HardwareDRM);
if (!supportsHardwareDrm)
{
    protectionManager.Properties["Windows.Media.Protection.UseSoftwareProtectionLayer"] = true;
}
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

Header.Text = supportsHardwareDrm ? "SUPPORTED" : "NOT SUPPRTED";

StreamSource.MediaProtectionManager = protectionManager;

mediaElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromMediaStreamSource(StreamSource);
```

I should be able to play playready DRM with a setup protection manager to start but down get any info on it so confused on the next step for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP `MediaElement` does not implement necessary support for PlayReady content coming from external sources. That is, there is no UWP PlayReday playback with `FFmpegMSS`.

You can have PlayReady only with Microsoft's own sources for streaming media.

Comment: So the question I have is codec based, like i need a HEVC codec to playback that doesn't use the hardware codec. But thank you for answering